# Translations metadata missing in Winter '18

Tags: translation, winter18

I am having trouble to retrieve "Translations" metadata from our sandboxes which are updated to Winter '18. Folder is just not there ( yes it is in package.xml )

There is no problem to get this metadata from our Prod which is still on Summer '17.

Btw I was trying to retrieve with MavensMate, Force.com IDE and workbench without any luck...

Can you guys replicate this issue? Did something changed to Translations metadata? How can we retrieve it in SF Win '18?

Thanks!

Comment: I would open a case with Salesforce. Based on what you describe, issues seems to be associated with '18 push.

Comment: Did that but as we have just Standard Support and this is considered as Developer issue they didn't bother to help...

Comment: did you try with ant? please post your package.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this message today from the agent working on the case (that I submitted to Salesforce Premier support).

" ...checked with the R&D team and currently they are QA ing the fix and I believe that the fix will be deployed in 210.8 Patch release which is due by next tuesday"

Comment: Got a firmer answer from Salesforce on this fix.... "The fix has been scheduled to release on 210.8 Patch which is on due next Tuesday 10/3/2017"